# Show only one of the categories of a post in the breadcrumb?

Tags: categories, slug

How does wordpress choose which category to display in the permalink if the post has multiple categories? I'm trying to display only a single category which wordpress included in the permalink (`/%category%/%postname%/`).

Comment: Is your question about permalinks or breadcrumbs? :-)

Comment: Usually the first category is used alphabetically, but posts can be directly accessed by all categories